# Is it possible to change the wallpaper depending on screen resolution?

Tags: windows-7, resolution, desktop-customization

I have a laptop with a resolution of 1680x1050.

At work I use 2x 1280x1024 monitors, and sometimes I present using a projector that is 1024x768.

My wallpaper, that I made for 1680x1050, looks awful on the other resolutions. Is there anything I can do that would make Windows 7 switch to a different wallpaper that has been cropped appropriately?

ie. can I give Windows more than one wallpaper, with different resolutions, and have Windows 7 switch automatically to a matching one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/). I believe it auto-fits your wallpaper to the new resolution whenever you switch to it. It also gives you several options for auto-fitting which can allow you to avoid any 'awful' results from Windows 7's default autofit.